# Best Way to Control Breathing During Pushups?

Tags: exercise-technique, push-ups, breathing

What is a good way to control my breathing while doing push-ups? I really want to be able to do 100 push-ups come next school year.

Currently, I can do 40 per set if I push myself. However, my breathing is terrible. I`m never sure when to inhale and exhale, so I end up holding my breath without realizing it. Then, after 5-6 push ups when I realize it, I inhale a ton of air. After repeating this over and over, I get tired out faster and I do push ups more slowly than I should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exhale on the push up, breathe in on the lower.

Lower slowly and explode upwards each time.